# How to close a cmd window and open a new one to continue the script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am making a batch file to simply open a cmd window. I am attempting to make a bit of a show before actually getting to the cmd window i can type commands in. 
Here's what i've come up with so far.

```
@echo off
ECHO Initializing super beeboop sequence...&& PAUSE
color 0a
:top
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
set /a top=%top%+1 
if "%top%"=="300" goto next
goto top
:next
pause 
goto next
START CMD
echo beep boop badoop
pause
START CMD /k
```

The problem is, after all the numbers go by i want the window to close and then open a new one which will enter "beep boop badoop". Which will close afterwards, finally opening the cmd window i can type in. Feel free to leave sugestions on how to fix/improve/add to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You created an infinite loop with the GOTO NEXT.  You will never get past the pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want it to do.  You just needed to string your commands together on one line.

```
@echo off
ECHO Initializing super beeboop sequence...& PAUSE
color 0a
:top
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
set /a top=%top%+1 
if "%top%"=="300" goto next
goto top
:next
pause 
Start CMD.exe /C "echo beep boop badoop & timeout /t 2 >nul & start cmd.exe /K"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That's exactly what I was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why so many `Cmd` sessions, and the need for the `GoTo`'s.

```bat
@Echo Off
Echo Initializing super beeboop sequence...
Color 0A
Timeout 3 /NoBreak>Nul
For /L %%A In (1 1 300) Do Echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%^
%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
Timeout 5 >Nul
ClS
Color
Echo beep boop badoop
Timeout -1
Start Cmd/K
```

Comment: Well you can ask why he wants 3 cmd sessions to open, but he did scope it in his question so I obliged in my answer.

Comment: I know, but they also asked for improvements, and for that I removed what seemed an unnecessary intermediate `Cmd` command.

Comment: I totally agree with you.